# How do I resize an R output table in markddown?

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I've been looking for some time to resize a table at markdown so it doesn't break. I thought about reducing the source or forcing it not to break, but how would I do that? I only found solutions using kable or kableextra, however I would like the default style. I left the data in the url.

[data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jacksonMaike/analises-r/3b4c594a82e8fc8ae3cf1aa93573577244fb8fed/datasets/medidas-resumo.csv)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could change the `width` in `options`.  Check the current `width` and make those changes

```
> head(cbind(iris, iris, iris))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7
  Petal.Width Species
1         0.2  setosa
2         0.2  setosa
3         0.2  setosa
4         0.2  setosa
5         0.2  setosa
6         0.4  setosa
> op <- options()
> options()$width # check the current width
[1] 167
> options(width = 300) # change the width and now do the print again
> head(cbind(iris, iris, iris))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Once we are done, reset the `options` again

```
> options(op)
> options()$width
[1] 167
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, it was great! I hadn't thought of tinkering with the options =/